# How to use thenAnswer with method which returns void

Tags: unit-testing, mockito

I want to unit test following method

```
public void addRecord(Record record)  
{  
   Myclass newObj = new Mycalss();  
   // It creates newObj object, set some values using record object.  
   // and it adds the newObj in daatbase.
   dataReqDao.persist(newObj);
}
```

I have mocked `dataReqDao.persist` method but how can I verify if right values are copied into newObj object? I want to get the newObj object.

I think `thenAnswer` will be the appropraite method to retrieve newObj ie method arguments but dont know how to use it method which returns void.

**Update:**
I tried

```
doAnswer(new Answer<Myclass>() {
              public Myclass answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                  Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                  return (Myclass)args[0];
              }

        }).when(dataReqDao.persist(any(Myclass.class)));
```

**EDIT:**
It should be (Thanks David)

```
 doAnswer(new Answer<Myclass>() {
                  public Myclass answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
                      Object[] args = invocation.getArguments();
                      return (Myclass)args[0];
                  }

            }).when(dataReqDao).persist(any(Myclass.class));
```

Comment: In your update, the brackets are in the wrong place.  I'm not sure whether that's the cause of your error, because the rest of it looks OK.  So it should be `doAnswer( ... ).when( dataReqDao ).persist( ... );`  Does that help?

Comment: @David: Thanks david. Actually I corrected that but forget to update my question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can create a custom [argument matcher](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.0/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#3) that would check fields of that object, or use an [argument captor](http://mockito.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.8.0/javadoc/org/mockito/Mockito.html#15) to capture the object for further inspection.

For example, as follows:

```
ArgumentCaptor<Myclass> c = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Myclass.class);
verify(dateReqDao).persist(c.capture());
Myclass newObj = c.getValue();

... // Validate newObj
```

Comment: This does not perform a clever test, since the ArgumentCaptor does not capture that state of the object at the time of call, but just the objectId. So even if you use setters in your method after the dao call, your test would be green. But a good test should fail with every functional change. I wrote my suggestion as an answer to the post.

Answer (score 2):

You need to make it with **thenAnswer** (or **then** which i personally prefer), so you can assert/verify the values at the time of method call, in the method.

```
 when(dataReqDao.persist(newObj)).then(new Answer<Void>() {
        @Override
        public Void answer(final InvocationOnMock invocation) {
            Myclass newObjActual = (Myclass) invocation.getArguments()[0];

            // Control
            assertEquals(..., newObjActual.getX());
            assertEquals(..., newObjActual.getY());
            return null;
        }
    });

 // Run Test
 x.addRecord(record);
```

Here is a detail explanation: https://akcasoy.wordpress.com/2015/04/09/the-power-of-thenanswer/ (Use case 2)

**ArgumentCaptor does not test in a clever way.** When you change your method like this:

```
public void addRecord(Record record)  
{  
   Myclass newObj = new Mycalss();  
   dataReqDao.persist(newObj);

   // first persist, than set attributes
   newObj.setX(..);
}
```

.. your test with Captor still runs, but it should fail. Since the ArgumentCaptor does not capture that state of the object at the time of call, but just the objectId, it does not matter for captor whether you set your attributes before or after dao call. Yet a good test should fail with every functional change. Here is my article exactly about this case:

https://akcasoy.wordpress.com/2015/02/03/how-to-ensure-quality-of-junit-tests/ (the above stubbing with the **then** is a better approach though than the one with InOrder approach)

Answer (score 0):

```
Myclass newObj = new Myclass();
```

That line troubles me.  If you are using dependency injection, you should have your factory send you an instance of that object.  Then, when you create your unit tests, you can have the test factory send in a mock instance of MyClass which the unit test can also have access to.  Then you can use axtavt's captor to see if it really did what it was supposed to do.  There's nothing wrong with the unit test the way you did it, it's just that any() is kind of weak given that you know it is passing in an object of that type--what you want to know in the test is whether the object is the one you intended and has not been modified.