# Mockito: How to use a thenAnswer call for multiple arguments

Tags: mockito

If you would like to extract, run or assert argument returned by or called to a method.

This will extract arguments from first and 2nd argument and return Ticket object.

```
when(mockTicketMaker.getTicket(any(Double.class),any(String.class)))
.thenAnswer(new Answer<String>(){

private int ticketNum=1;

@Override public Ticket answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) throws Throwable {

    Double price=(Double)invocation.getArguments()[0];
    String destination = (String) invocation.getArguments()[1];
    assertEquals(new Double(123.56), price);

  return new Ticket();
}
  }
);
```

Comment: is this a question or a statement?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to assert on the arguments passed to a method. Rather than use an inline answer and assert within the answer, a more elegant solution is provided by Mockito in the form of [the ArgumentCaptor<> class](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/ArgumentCaptor.html).

Given

```
public class TicketMaker {

    public void getTicket(Double arg1, String arg2) {

    }

}
```

You can write the following in a test

```
@Test
public void captureArguments() {
    TicketMaker mockTicketMaker = Mockito.mock(TicketMaker.class);

    mockTicketMaker.getTicket(23.0d, "something");

    ArgumentCaptor<Double> doubleCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Double.class);
    ArgumentCaptor<String> stringCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(String.class);
    Mockito.verify(mockTicketMaker).getTicket(doubleCaptor.capture(), stringCaptor.capture());

    assertThat(doubleCaptor.getValue()).isEqualTo(23.0d);
    assertThat(stringCaptor.getValue()).isEqualTo("something");
}
```

Comment: For those curious, I'm using the Fest library for fluent assertion - https://code.google.com/p/fest/

Comment: This does not perform a clever test, since the ArgumentCaptor does not capture that state of the object at the time of call, but just the objectId.. When the order of matters you should make it with thenAnswer. Look at the example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8755753/how-to-use-thenanswer-with-method-which-returns-void/29556171#29556171