# How to control the response with the Elasticsearch async api

Tags: java, unit-testing, elasticsearch, mockito

How can I control the `IndexResponse` when using the Elasticsearch [async api](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high-document-index.html#java-rest-high-document-index-async) w/ the `HighLevelRestClient` v7.5?

Maybe I need to mock the [Low Level REST Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-low.html) and use that mock for my [High Level REST Client](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/master/java-rest-high.html)?

```java
@Test
void whenIndexResponseHasFailuresDoItShouldReturnFalse() {

  // arrange
  var indexResponse = mock(IndexResponse.class);
  when(indexResponse.getResult()).thenReturn(Result.UPDATED);

  var restHighLevelClient = mock(RestHighLevelClient.class);
  when(restHighLevelClient.indexAsync())
      //do something here??

  var indexReqest = new IndexRequest(...);

  //act
  var myHelper = new MyHelper(restHighLevelClient);
  var result = myHelper.doIt(indexReqest)
    .get();

  //assert
  assert(result).isFalse();
}
```

```java
class MyHelper {

  //injected RestHighLevelClient

  CompletableFuture<Boolean> doIt(Customer customer) {

    var result = new CompletableFuture<Boolean>();
    var indexRequest = new IndexRequest(...);

    restHighLevelClient.indexAsync(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT
         , new ActionListener<IndexResponse>() {
      @Override
      public void onResponse(IndexResponse indexResponse) {  //want to control indexResponse
        if (indexResponse.getResult() == Result.UPDATED) {
          result.complete(false);
        } else {
          result.complete(true);
        }
      }

      @Override
      public void onFailure(Exception e) {
        ...
      }
    });

    return result;
  }
}
```

**Update**
[Sample project](https://github.com/spottedmahn/experiments-2020/tree/master/elastic-async-mocking) using Oleg's answer

Comment: Refactor your code. You can't unit test if  `RestHighLevelClient` is created in `doIt`

Comment: It’s not, I’ll update my question, it’s injected, good point, thanks  @Oleg

Comment: Feel free to ignore this comment and not answer, it doesn't really matter anyway, I'm just curious; why did you accept my answer but didn't upvote it?

Comment: Hi @Oleg - I'm experimenting/researching, I've usually accepted and upvoted.  [Interesting read](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/686/accepting-answer-without-upvoting).  Before I upvoted, in this case, I wanted to research "should I accept and upvote or just accept?  what's the 'right' way?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mock `RestHighLevelClient` then inside `indexAsync` mock `IndexResponse` and pass it to the `ActionListener`.

```
RestHighLevelClient restHighLevelClient = mock(RestHighLevelClient.class);
when(restHighLevelClient.indexAsync(any(), any(), any())).then(a -> {
    ActionListener<IndexResponse> listener = a.getArgument(2);
    IndexResponse response = mock(IndexResponse.class);
    when(response.getResult()).then(b -> {
        return Result.UPDATED;
    });
    listener.onResponse(response);
    return null;
});
MyHelper myHelper = new MyHelper(restHighLevelClient);
Boolean result = myHelper.doIt(null).get();
assertFalse(result);
```

Also, configure Mockito to support mocking final methods otherwise a [NPE](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/null-pointer-exception-in-java/) will be thrown when mocking `indexAsync`.

[*Option 1*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44422008/185123)

> Instead of using the mockito-core artifact, include the mockito-inline artifact in your project

[*Option 2*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53837478)

> Create a file `src/test/resources/mockito-extensions/org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker` with `mock-maker-inline` as the content

Comment: restHighLevelClient.indexAsync() is void method. How do you any return ? for Mockito.when()

Comment: I don't understand. What return?

Comment: Something should "return" in Mockito.when(). Since indexAsync() is void, it doesn't "return" anything. I just asked how this will happen.

Comment: @MuratKara It's not a problem. https://stackoverflow.com/a/29556171/1398418